# Looking for layout xml files for the project

Tags: xml, file, layout, location, basic4android

I have saved several layout files with the designer but tried to look at them in Notepad and found they were not xml files.

If I want to edit the xml layout files, can you tell me how to find the xml files so I can edit them in Notepad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic4android doesn't use XML files. The designer files are saved as binary files with "bal" extension.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I used to use Eclipse I used to copy and paste the layout properties that I liked from 1 layout xml file to others that I wanted to use the same properties. Apart from copying entire .bal files, can a set of properties be copied from one project to another or between 1 .bal file to the other?

Comment: You cannot copy a part of a bal file. You can however share the UI by creating smaller bal files and loading them to panels instead of activities.